# Regex: How to remove extra spaces between filename in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, filenames

How to remove extra spaces between filenames in Perl

leading and trailing spaces can be removed by regex $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//x;

This is what my code looks like:

```
use File::Find;
find (\&wanted, '.');
sub wanted {
    my $file = $File::Find::name;
    $file =~ s/\$//g;
    print "**file = $file\n";
}
```

`$file` can be:

```
My File.jpg
myfile$
$myfile
my$file
```

To remove `$` from my filenames i am using `$file =~ s/\$//g;` will this work for the spaces too?

Comment: When you say "between filenames", do you actually mean "inside a filename"?

Comment: This is how my code looks likeuse File::Find;

find (\&wanted, '.');

sub wanted {
  my $file = $File::Find::name;
  $file =~ s/\$//g; 
  print "**file = $file\n";
}

Comment: My file name is like "My File.jpg" or "myfile$" or $myfile" or "my$file" for removing $ from my filenames i am using $file =~ s/\$//g; will this work for the spaces too??

Answer (score 1):

```
$file =~ s/\s+/ /g;
```

Will remove consecutive whitespace characters and replace them with a single space.

Comment: for removing $ from my filenames i am using $file =~ s/\$//g; will this work for the spaces too??

Comment: Yes, why would it not work? Though what you are going to do with such a list, I have no idea. Sounds like you are attempting the wrong thing.

Comment: i have to remove all the whitespaces and $ occurances in my file names for example "My File.jpg" "My  Pic.png" "Myfolder$" "mytest$"

Answer (score -1):

For multiple space chunks in the middle of your string what you can do is split the string by the regex for space chunks and then join the full sting using the `split(/\s+/, $data)` and `join(" ", @LIST)` functions in perl.

As pointed by @TLP here is the updated code using just regex:

```
$str =~ s/\s+/ /g;
```

Comment: The substitution operator s/// can manipulate strings just fine.

Comment: Thanks Shubhanshu but my intention is to just process filename and do some manipulation on it. I want to remove spaces from filename like "My File.jpg" or "My   Data.png"